# Java capture outputfile from external process

Tags: java, redirect, process, path, intercept

In Java, I want to write an application which is capable of starting another process (e.g. Microsoft Word) and then intercept the creation of a new file in order to retrieve its name and link it to my application without having to add it by hand. I was able to run Microsoft Word, but I cannot find a solution as to how to find out if a file has been created. I also tried running other programmes such as CodeBlocks from my Java application and was able to fetch the inputstream but this did not contain any filepath. I still do not know how to redirect the filepath to my Java application.

Is this possible without monitoring the whole system?

Comment: I think this will be a separate problem for each program, and you will be limited by what the program outputs.  Does Word even give any outputs like that?  What about an API (if one exists)?

Comment: No, Word does not output anything. I guess I have to think of another solution such as monitoring a certain folder.